# logstash: Unknown setting ‘“index”’ for elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm new to the elastic search concept to make connection with mySQL. 
I followed multiple tutorials to install but I'm getting these errors:
Unknown setting '"index"'and '"host'" for elasticsearch

The output of

```
sudo -Hu root /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --path.settings /etc/logstash/
```

returns:

```
> Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties 
> [2019-04-20T17:48:47,293][INFO ][logstash.runner ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.0.0"} 
> [2019-04-20T17:48:53,873][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Unknown setting '"document_type"' for elasticsearch 
> [2019-04-20T17:48:53,878][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Unknown setting '"hosts"' for elasticsearch > [2019-04-20T17:48:53,878][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Unknown setting '"index"' for elasticsearch 
> [2019-04-20T17:48:53,891][ERROR][logstash.agent ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Something is wrong with your configuration.", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:86:inconfig_init'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:60:in initialize'", "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/OutputStrategyExt.java:232:ininitialize'", "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/OutputDelegatorExt.java:48:in initialize'", "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/OutputDelegatorExt.java:30:ininitialize'", "org/logstash/plugins/PluginFactoryExt.java:239:in plugin'", "org/logstash/plugins/PluginFactoryExt.java:137:inbuildOutput'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:50:in initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:23:ininitialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:36:in execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:325:inblock in converge_state'"]}
> [2019-04-20T17:48:54,190][INFO ][logstash.agent ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
> [2019-04-20T17:48:59,066][INFO ][logstash.runner ] Logstash shut down.
```

Here is the content of the logstash.conf file:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/archief"
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "pswxxx"
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    # our query
    statement => "SELECT * FROM archief"
    }
  }
output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
  "hosts" => ["localhost:9200"]
  "index" => "archief"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no double quotes in the options name.

```
output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "archief"
  }
}
```

Comment: Looked promising, but it gives the same error. The strangest thing is that it seems to load some other config file I cannot locate because it throws the 'Unknown setting '"document_type"' ' error and document_type is not specified.

Comment: Do you have any other file in the logstash conf dir? If your configuration doesn't have a `document_type` option, it probably is trying to load another file too. What is the configuration in your `logstash.yml` ?

Comment: solved, the conf was located in /etc/logstash/conf.d/ even when using --path.settings /etc/logstash/

Comment: `--path.settings` points only to the directory containing the `logstash.yml` file, to change the config directory you need to use `--path.config` or `-f`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and solved it by changing my logstash version from 7.4.2 to 6.3.2.

[Logstash 6.3.2 link](https://www.elastic.co/fr/downloads/past-releases/logstash-6-3-2)